# How to loop through different functions / filter methods (or different statements) in python pandas in each loop

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops

I want to loop through different filter methods in my code.

This is what my code looks like.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(..................)

datelist = [ datetime.date(2021, 5, 10),
 datetime.date(2021, 5, 11),
 datetime.date(2021, 5, 12),
 datetime.date(2021, 5, 13),
 datetime.date(2021, 5, 14),
 datetime.date(2021, 5, 17),
 datetime.date(2021, 5, 18),
 datetime.date(2021, 5, 19)]

for date in datelist:
    dfr = pd.read_sql(f"select * from frame1 where date = '{date}'",index_col='date',con=engine)
    dfr = dfr.pivot_table(columns='line')
    dfc = pd.read_sql(f"select * from frame2 where date = '{date}'",index_col='date',con=engine)
    dfc = dfc.pivot_table(columns='line')
    dff = dfr.append(dfc)
    dff.columns = [x.lower() for x in dff.columns]
    
    ### want to for loop this part with a different statement everytime
    dff.loc['test', :] = dff.loc['indicator1'].ge(0).eq(dff.loc['indicator2']) 
    dff = dff.loc[:,(dff.loc['indicator3']>0)]
    ### until here

    indicator = dff.loc["indicator3",:]
    dictionary = list(future_returns.to_dict().keys())
    
    some_save_functions()
```

If you take a look at the commented part, i want to loop through various filter methods there.

Below are examples of different filter method I want to try.

function1

```
dff.loc['test', :] = dff.loc['indicator1'].ge(0).eq(dff.loc['indicator2']) 
dff = dff.loc[:,(dff.loc['indicator3']>0)]
```

function2

```
dff.loc['test', :] = dff.loc['indicator6'].ge(0).eq(dff.loc['indicator7']) 
dff = dff.loc[:,(dff.loc['test']==True) & (dff.loc['indicator3']>0)]
```

function3

```
...... 
......
```

The statements could look very different each time.

I have 8 dates above, and I have 6 filter methods. At the end I want to save 8 x 6 frames.

Can this be done? I have no idea. I have only ever looped through variables, never different statements.

I was thinking of using a class or defining a function for each filter, but I don’t know how to loop through those either. Is there a way to do this with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert each filtering method into a [function()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function) that will return a single array or list, you might be able to replace the commented block with a for loop in the following format:

```
# List of filtering functions as strings without the ()
list_of_methods = ["np.sum", "np.mean", "np.std"]

for method in list_of_methods:
    # Converts each method into the filtering_function() at a time
    exec("filtering_function = " + method)
    
    # Appends the resulting list of results fomr the filtering_function() to the original dataset
    dff[method] = filtering_function(dff)
```

In the end, you will have a DataFrame with as many columns as filtering functions. You can even customize the name of the columns when appending them to the DataFrame with the following chunk of code:

```
col_name = method + "_results"
dff[col_name] = filtering_function(dff)
```

Comment: Interesting answer, I have been doing something similar but using class functions